# create overlapping linerlayout with buttons and listview in framelayout android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a frame layout which has the first child as a listview

and the second child as a linear layout with few buttons

some thing like this, this is just an example image not the actual image

[image]

this is the code I am trying

```
    <Framelayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/viewlist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sort_by_alpha_white_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_white_48dp" />



            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/shuffle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:clickable="true"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle_white_48dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00000000"
                 android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00000000"
                 android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />


             <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00000000"
                 android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_applications_white_48dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </Framelayout>
```

the buttons are displayed , and the listview bellow it is also displayed but when I click on the button the list item is clicked and that event is triggered

the button click listeners are like these

```
shuffle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "shuffle clicked ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

and listvew has

```
 getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

        }
    };
```

How can I make the Layout containing buttons overlap the listview and still be clickable

Comment: use Relativelayout inside the framelayout , then use the listview and content of buttons inside the relative layout.

Comment: tried that as well , still the listview item was clicked

Comment: Try to set listener for the header layout. It might prevent the listitem click listener . Its just a workaround.

Comment: Why do you need framelayout? why not relative layout?

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable by changing your design in a way that, the layout containing buttons will be included in a frame layout as a final child(Relative Layout). Which will allow you to overlap the Listview design and still buttons are clickable.

```
 <Framelayout>
   <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<RelativeLayout
>
<!-- your button layout design !-->
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout>
```